Firefox HAR export stops working when cache reaches a certain size
I've had problems with HAR file export before: How to make browser developer tools save HAR file containing untruncated response? However, that was about the size of individual response bodies. After setting devtools.netmonitor.responseBodyLimit accordingly, the response bodies are not getting truncated anymore.
However, if too many cached responses accumulate, clicking to save the HAR file simply doesn't respond anymore. Nothing happens. This behavior begins somewhere between 450 MB and 650 MB of data, because I found successful HAR exports with 450 MB, and just failed to export one with 650 MB.
I assume, there's another setting in about:config that might help me here? Any ideas?

I don't think you're right about this being another setting. Probably, the browser is struggling somehow to process that much data. I'm having the same problem.
